# Regex for phone number +7 - XXX - XXX - XX - XX

Tags: c#, regex, string

My phone number must be in this format.

```
+7 - XXX - XXX - XX - XX
```

I am trying to make regex for that

```
"+7 - \d{3} - \d{3} - \d{2} - \d{2}"
```

But this didn't working. Please help.

Comment: What problem did you have?

Comment: and why that didnt work ?

Comment: "+7 - \d{3} - \d{3} - \d{2} - \d{2}"
This regex didn't working.

Comment: You have to escape `+` symbol as `\+`.

Comment: What string are you using the regex on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `+` quantifier.

```
\+7 - \d{3} - \d{3} - \d{2} - \d{2}
^ here
```

You can use `^` and `$` anchors around your regex to make it exact matching.

Also, you can use `[ ]+` instead of space to consider multiple spaces in between the numbers.